# how to differentiate between these entries?

Tags: php

I have a new question about a project I had been working on. I was designing a grid with different colored cells. it has a hidden div which shows when a cell is clicked, however I realized that only one cell(the last one of it's type) will show. i.e. if I have 2 objects with the column "objaffinity" as 0 ("enemy") it will show both red cells on the grid, however only the last one will actually work.
how can I make it so that it will show the proper information for each cell?

here's my code:

mapgen.php:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cellinfo.js"></script>

<script src="cmenu.js"></script>
<?php
require("sql.php");
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `maps`
    WHERE `objpresent` = 1
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']'); 
} // ran the query
//$xobj = array();
//$yobj = array();
$otype = array();
$oname = array();
$xyobj = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $xyobj[$row['x']][$row['y']] = true;
  $otype[$row['id']]=$row['objaffinity'];
   $oname[$row['id']]=$row['object'];
}

// get the rows
$cellid=1;
//find whether the row is obstructed

for ($y = 0; $y < 20; $y++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($x = 0; $x < 25; $x++) {
        echo "<td>";
        //Detect what type of object it is
        if (isset($xyobj[$x][$y])) {

        if($otype[$cellid] == 2)
        {
          echo "<a href='#'> <div class='foe'> </div><div class='foepopup'>";
          echo $oname[$cellid];
            echo "</div></a>";
        }
        elseif($otype[$cellid] == 1)
        {
     echo "<a href='#'><div class='friend'></div><div class='friendpopup'>";
          echo $oname[$cellid];
            echo "</div></a>";
        }
        else
        {
     echo "<a href='#'> <div class='neutral'></div><div class='neutralpopup'>";
          echo $oname[$cellid];
            echo "</div></a>";
        }



            $cellid++;
            }


        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}


?>
```

Cellinfo.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//initially hide all popups
$(".foepopup").hide();
$(".neutralpopup").hide();
$(".friendpopup").hide();


//foebutton selected
$(".foe").on("click",function(e){
$(".friendpopup").hide();
$(".neutralpopup").hide();
$(".foepopup").show();
});
//close foe when selected
$(".foepopup").on("click",function(e){
$(".foepopup").hide();
});

//neutral button pressed
$(".neutral").on("click",function(e){
$(".foepopup").hide();
$(".friendpopup").hide();
$(".neutralpopup").show();
});
//close neutral
$(".neutralpopup").on("click",function(e){
$(".neutralpopup").hide();
});

//friend button pressed
$(".friend").on("click",function(e){
$(".foepopup").hide();
$(".neutralpopup").hide();
$(".friendpopup").show();
});
//close friend
$(".friendpopup").on("click",function(e){
$(".friendpopup").hide();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functions you use selectors, so for the script it does not matter which div was clicked.
Let me show you some examples:

```
$(".foepopup").on("click",function(e){
    $(".foepopup").hide();
});
```

It should be something like this rather:

```
$(".foepopup").on("click",function(e){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

And another example:

```
$(".neutral").on("click",function(e){
    $(".foepopup").hide();
    $(".friendpopup").hide();
    $(".neutralpopup").show();
});
```

Rewrite it like this:

```
$(".neutral").on("click",function(e){
    var td_tag = $(this).parent().parent();
    td_tag.children(".foepopup").hide();
    td_tag.children(".friendpopup").hide();
    td_tag.children(".neutralpopup").show();
});
```

Rewrite other code on your own. `this` is the element on which click was triggered. `td_tag` will contain parent cell of a div clicked. After that, `children` method will allow you to find needed elements already inside specific cell.
Good luck!

Comment: I should note a change that is important in this case: since each cell only contains one type, but I want to hide any other popups, this:   `td_tag.children(".friendpopup").hide();` actually needs to be `$(".friendpopup").hide();` to work. the showing part works fine  because it has to be specific. also, `.children()` didn't seem to work but `.find()` did work. with these small edits the code now works good. thanks!